# How to apply Tailwind CSS styles to the HTML response from API on runtime?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How to apply Tailwind CSS styles to the HTML response from API on runtime?

I have a project in which I requested an API that gave me an HTML response.

```
<div class="bg-blue-900">Test</div>
```

Now, since I didn't use the `bg-blue-900` class before in my project, `bg-blue-900` CSS styles didn't get generated. How do I apply Tailwind CSS styles to the HTML response from API on runtime?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the API response you're getting? I will try to figure out a solution for you. And are you using Reactjs?

Comment: It's mostly common sections of HTML with tailwind classes. It can vary since it will be used in Custom Site Editor which I'm making. And In addition to server response. I am making a system in which users can also add tailwind classes in that Custom Site Editor. The problem is tailwind Classes styles are not generated on runtime.

Comment: Can you try using tailwind CDN https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn  . Most probably this way it will start picking up classes you put in your custom site editor.

Comment: This is what I end up doing. But I don't know if it is a right choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to the safelist in the tailwind config.

```
safelist: [
    'bg-blue-900',
    or for all bg colors ...
    {
      pattern: /^bg-/,
    },
  ]
```